# Git... Branches Dedicated to CSS, Comments, & Refactoring? Is it a good idea?

Tags: git, github

My commit history for my github project is a big mess because I make so many different changes (especially with commenting) that makes it hard to see what has been changed. Recently I had the idea to put styling, commenting, and refactoring on separate branches, but I'm not sure the branching system was intended for that? I'm still learning git, but from what I understand branching is mainly used for working on a new feature. So my question is, is my idea practical, and if so how would it be implemented?

The alternative I suppose is just making a bunch of very small commits of refactors, commenting changes, etc. But that also doesn't seem like a great solution because then I'll have a ton of 1 and 2 line commits.

Comment: "very small commits of refactors, commenting changes" <--- THIS. Having many "atomic" commits is a good thing, IMO, because it makes it easy for you to revert changes later, if needed.

Comment: If those pieces you mention (CSS, comments...) are completely independent, then consider start a separate git project for each of them. If they're not independent (which is probably the case), that's probably not a good idea. Using clear commit messages might help. For example, you can prepend a word to all your commit messages to give some you context (something like "css: change background colour" or "refactoring: updated header and footer").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only branching won't solve your problem. Let's say you made a dedicated branch for CSS changes and made 10 small commits to it. Once the branch is merged in master, master will have those 10 commits as well.

Branching will surely help you to segregate your work of refactoring. What you can do in addition to branching is squashing your commits before they are merged in to master.
With squashing, you can turn your 10 commits in to one single commit and name it as CSS changes. And then you can merge that single commit to master.

You can do squashing with the help of [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Please note: Rebase is an operation that changes history. So, never try it on shared commits unless you know what you are doing. Rebase is absolutely safe if you have local commits that haven't been pushed to remote yer and you want to play [squash, delete, reorder, etc.] around them.